# How to get click event on a html button from webview?

Tags: java, android, html, android-webview, dom-events

This question may sound basic for many of you. But please take a look at my actual problem. I am setting content of my WebView dynamically in my android application. 
And I am able to set text in it without having any problem but my problem is I need to add some button dynamically into my WebView as below

```
for (Address address : (List<Address>) childDataList.get(3)) {

    if (!address.getName().equalsIgnoreCase("")) {
        text.append("<b>").append(address.getName()).append("</b>");
    }


    /*  dynamic button in html */
   //text.append("<br>").append("<a href=\"http://www.google.com\" target=\"_parent\"><button>Navigation </button></a>");   // this is working
   text.append("<br>").append("<button type=\"button\" onclick=\"ok.performClick();\">Navigation</button>");    // not able to make it work
   text.append("<br><br>");

}
```

And I am calling this method using the below code:

```
WebSettings ws = wv.getSettings();
ws.setJavaScriptEnabled(true);
wv.addJavascriptInterface(new Object()
{
  public void performClick()
  {
    //Print Toast
  }
}, "ok");
```

However `performClick()` method is not calling on button click, while it is working perfectly incase of direct url. So if you have any suggestion or link please provide for me.

I followed [android html button onclick event](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22153266/android-html-button-onclick-event) and [webviews html button click detection in activityjava code](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20917235/webviews-html-button-click-detection-in-activityjava-code) and [detect click on html button through javascript in android webview](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4065312/detect-click-on-html-button-through-javascript-in-android-webview) link, but I am unable get my requirement done.

And I am setting my webview text programmatically Android code not in Javascript. So please take a look at my question before marking it as duplicate or if I missing something then guide me.

Answer (score 0):

You need to annotate `performClick` with `@JavascriptInterface` ([doc](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/webkit/JavascriptInterface.html)) in your Java code:

```
wv.addJavascriptInterface(new Object()
{
    @JavascriptInterface
    public void performClick()
    {
        //Print Toast
    }
}, "ok");
```

Also, make sure that you are calling `addJavascriptInterface` *before* loading your page.

Comment: I have a doubt here does the name performClick has to match both in Java as well as javascript if i change perform click to any other text will the click still work ?

Comment: Yes, your calls in JavaScript must use the name of the Java function. If you rename it, you will have to change your JavaScript code accordingly.